# Parenthesization in Lambda Calculus

Tags: discrete-mathematics, definition, computer-science, formal-languages, lambda-calculus

I am trying to understand how parenthesization works in $λ$-calculus. All of the resources state the following:

- Applications are left associative;
- Abstractions are right associative and extend as much as possible.

When it comes to applications from what I understand this means  that it is not associative, that is: $$(ab)c \neq a(bc)$$ and the right way to fully parenthesize the expression $abc$ would be:
$$((a b)c)$$

However I do not understand the part of abstraction, what does it mean to extend as much as possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding of left associativity for applications is perfect.

Concerning abstractions, the fact that they "are right associative and extend as much as possible" means that:

- a term $\lambda x . N_1 N_2 \dots N_n$ must be read as $\lambda x. (N_1 N_2 \dots N_n)$ ("abstractions extend as much as possible");
  for instance, $\lambda x. M N P$ must be read as $\lambda x. (M N P)$, and not as $(\lambda x. (M N))P$;
- a term $\lambda x_1 . \lambda x_2. \dots \lambda x_n. N$ must be read as $\lambda x_1. (\lambda x_2. \dots (\lambda x_n. N) \dots )$ ("abstractions are right associative");
  for instance, $\lambda x. \lambda y. \lambda z. N$ must be read as $\lambda x. (\lambda y. (\lambda z. N))$; note that any other parenthesization, for instance $\lambda x. ((\lambda y.\lambda z). N)$, would not yield a term, because $(\lambda y. \lambda z.)$ is not a term.

Comment: Do the parentheses make a difference when it comes to interpretation though? Take this example $λx.λy.λz.xyz$ . The way I interpret is : Wait for argument $x$,wait for argument $y$,wait for argument $z$ then apply $x$ to $y$ and finally apply $(x y)$ to $z$.However how would one interpret the following : $$λz.(λf.λx.fzx) (λy.y)$$ It is the explicit use of parenthesis in this example that confuses me.

Comment: @RookieCookie - That term is not normal, there is a $\beta$-redex, indeed $λz.(λf.λx.fzx)(λy.y) \to_\beta λz.λx.(λy.y)zx \to_\beta λz.λx.zx$. The last term is normal and its meaning is clear: wait for argument $z$, wait for argument $x$ and apply $z$ to $x$. The interpretation of the original term would be the same, but is presented in a more convoluted way because the term is not normal.